# Integer column data still not shown in latest 0.96 browser

Tags: macos, realm, osx-elcapitan

I've downloaded Realm 0.96.2 for Swift 2.1 and Xcode 7.1. I downloaded the latest Beta of the Realm browser (About box shows "Version 0.96 (17)") as linked to from the Realm documentation page but it still does not expand the integer columns wide enough to display their contents. You can just see part of the contents at the far right of the columns. I can resize them manually but it's a pain to do this every time I relaunch the browser.

I'm running OS X 10.11.1

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** There is already a [newer release](https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/releases/tag/0.96.1), which fixes this issue. I'll take care of updating the documentation accordingly.

Thanks for bringing this again to our attention. We are already tracking that by [issue #78 in the Realm Browser repo](https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/issues/78). You may want to subscribe to the issue there, to be informed as soon as this is fixed.

Comment: Thanks so much Marius - now sorted! :-)